# Custom inspection for PhpStorm to detect missing empty line from end of file?

Tags: phpstorm

For git it is recommended to include empty line at the end of the file. I'd like to create [custom inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-custom-inspections.html) in PhpStorm IDE that detects files that are missing this empty line, however docs for those inspections are rather scarce.

It would be nice to be able to add them automatically too.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General --> Ensure line feed at file end on Save` ?

Comment: @LazyOne This is only partial solution that works when you create/edit a file yourself. I don't want this only for save action. Sometimes I have to review or fix other people code and this inspection would be very handy for that.